# Copy-Item command in powershell: problem with credentials

Tags: windows, powershell, server

I am writing a powershell script that copies a .jar file from a server to a remote VM. When it gets to the Copy-Item command, it fails with this error:

```
Copy-Item : The user name or password is incorrect.
+     Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination '\\consolidate\c$ ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comma 
   nds.CopyItemCommand
```

I have tried adding a -Credentials argument to the Copy-Item command. That gives me this error:

```
The FileSystem provider supports credentials only on the New-PSDrive cmdlet. 
Perform the operation again without specifying credentials.
At [file path]
+     Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination '\\consolidate\c$ ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:) [], PSNotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupported
```

Here is the code around the line in question:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String $vmPwd
$user = "consolidate\$vmUser"
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $user,$password

Invoke-Command -ComputerName "consolidate" -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock {
    New-PSDrive -Name "X" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "C:\" -Credential $Using:credentials
}

Copy-Item -Path $calcEngineJarPath -Destination '\\consolidate\c$'

...

Remove-PSDrive X
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to create a new PSDrive *on your local machine* that maps the network path to a drive letter:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String $vmPwd
$user = "consolidate\$vmUser"
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $user,$password

# Create mapped network drive
New-PSDrive -Name "X" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\consolidate\c$\" -Credential $credentials

# Copy to mapped network drive
Copy-Item -Path $calcEngineJarPath -Destination X:\
```

---

Alternatively, use `Copy-Item`'s `-ToSession` parameter:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String $vmPwd
$user = "consolidate\$vmUser"
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $user,$password

# Create a new PSRemoting session on the target machine using the credentials
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName consolidate -Credentials $credentials

# Copy file to remote session drive
Copy-Item -Path $calcEngineJarPath -Destination C:\ -ToSession $session
```